# Is it possible to call methods by name?

Tags: java, methods, metaprogramming

I am building a small quiz application, and I am storing each answer to each question in a database table (using JPA).

I wonder if there is a way to fetch the getters dynamically through a for loop for example (as is possible with javascript), rather than to have to write out each get method.

The code I have (where "answer" is a class with 9 different integers for each answer).

```
public void parseUserScore(UserAnswers answer) {
    Integer[] answers = new Integer[] {
            answer.getQ1(),
            answer.getQ2(),
            answer.getQ3(),
            answer.getQ4(),
            answer.getQ5(),
            answer.getQ6(),
            answer.getQ7(),
            answer.getQ8(),
            answer.getQ9()
    };
    double totalscore = 0;
    Integer answeredQuestions = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        if (answers[i] > 0) {
            answeredQuestions++;
        }
        totalscore += answers[i];
    }
}
```

My question is if it is possible to fetch these answers through a foor loop like so:

```
public void parseUserScore(UserAnswers answer) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        String methodname = "getQ" + i.toString();
        list.add(i, answer.methodname)
    }   
}
```

This would be preferable since I would like to use the index of each question to separate them based on their respective categories.

Comment: Why doesn't the `UserAnswers` just maintain a `List<Integer> answers`?

Comment: No, because your answers aren't in an array or a list. You could use reflection, but that's a poor solution to a design issue.

Comment: Hint: as soon as you start writing code that does name things a1, a2, a3, ... you are doing something wrong. Then you have to step back and figure how to organize your data/code to use lists/arrays.

Comment: It would be preferable to use an array for the questions, but I could not get the mapping with JPA to work to map the individual columns to an array in JPA. So I had to map each column to a separate integer...

Answer (score 2):

From what you provided in your question I think you should use three entities: `User`, `Question` and `Answer`. A user can ask multiple question and submit multiple answers to questions. An answer belongs always to one question. JPA has some annotations to model these rules:

```
@Entity
class User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    Set<Question> questions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    Set<Answer> answers;

    // Getters & setters

}

@Entity
class Question {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    Set<Answer> answers;

    // Getters & setters

}

@Entity
class Answer {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    Question question;

    int score;

    // Getters & setters

}
```

Afterwards you can simply iterate over the answers of a particular user and calculate the total score:

```
final int totalScore = user.getAnswers().stream().mapToInt(Answer::getScore).sum();
```

Please note that this is only a basic example. You should also make considerations about cascading updates and fetch types of the relations.

Regarding you question about the for loop: Java provides a feature called 'Reflection'. It is a mechanism for meta-programming and could be used to achieve what you described. However, this is a bad idea because it has some drawbacks and it makes no sense in your case as a user should be able to answer more than 10 questions. In fact you can not know how many answers a user will submit.

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna post an answer with reflection and try to discourage OP using it (by doing something like you did), but now that you posted this I'm just gonna upvote you. However, you should add why reflection isn't a good idea (even though it's in the comments).